# Are Azure RBAC additive or the least permissible role wins?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, rbac

I would like to know the effect of Azure RBAC resource roles. If say i have a "storage blob data contributor" role assigned at the Storage Account Level and and a "storage blob reader role" assigned at the Container Level, which one will take effect, the container role or the one set at the Storage Account Layer since it is at a higher level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure RBAC roles are additive. From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview#multiple-role-assignments):

> So what happens if you have multiple overlapping role assignments?
> **Azure RBAC is an additive model, so your effective permissions are the
> sum of your role assignments**. Consider the following example where a
> user is granted the Contributor role at the subscription scope and the
> Reader role on a resource group. The sum of the Contributor
> permissions and the Reader permissions is effectively the Contributor
> role for the subscription. Therefore, in this case, the Reader role
> assignment has no impact.

In your case, if you have "Storage Blob Data Contributor" role assigned at the Storage Account Level and and a "Storage Blob Reader Role" assigned at the Container Level, then the user will have "Storage Blob Data Contributor" role at the container level.